# Test Atmosphere Websocket using wscat

Tags: java, spring-boot, atmosphere

I try to build a java application using atmosphere for supporting websocket connections. I do not see how I can test my application to see if it works, using the wscat library to connect to it.

Whenever I make a call with wscat like `wscat -c ws://localhost:8090/ws` I get `error: Unexpected server response: 404`

When I had my own non-atmosĥere implementation, the wscat succeeded and was able to reveive messages on the websocket. What do I miss to make atmosphere work?

Answer (score 0):

Silly of me, but I forgot to define the atmosphere servlet. Once I did that, it all worked.